# How use New keyword to create a New object in VB6, such as new button, label, etc

Tags: vb6, activex

I have a program that get several names, and save them in a file. I want to create a new object (button, label, etc) for every person that saved in the file. I use this code, but I got error :

```
Dim i as new object
set i= new button
```

The error that I got :
ActiveX Component can't create object

Comment: Are you only asking about creating on-screen controls? The term "object" is much broader than that.

Comment: I want a clickable object, that I could show a page, for every person

Answer (score 2):

In your Form, add a Label and a Command Button. I assume you already did this.

Select the label and, inside the Properties Window, set  `lblPerson` to the `Name` property and `0` to the `Index` property.

Select the button and, inside the Properties Window, set `cmdPerson` to the `Name` property and `0` to the `Index` property.

Now you have two Control Arrays which you can dynamically set at runtime:

```
Public Sub AddPersonListControls(idx As Long)
    Load cmdPerson(idx)
    cmdPerson(idx).Caption = "Details"
    cmdPerson(idx).Visible = True
    cmdPerson(idx).Top = cmdPerson(idx - 1).Top + cmdPerson(idx - 1).Height + 10
    cmdPerson(idx).Left = cmdPerson(0).Left

    Load lblPerson(idx)
    lblPerson(idx).Caption = "Person Name " & idx
    lblPerson(idx).Visible = True
    lblPerson(idx).Top = lblPerson(idx - 1).Top + lblPerson(idx - 1).Height + 10
    lblPerson(idx).Left = lblPerson(0).Left
End Sub
```

Wherever you load the data of your Persons, create the corresponding controls:

```
Dim numPersons As Long 
numPersons = 3 ' just an example
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To numPersons - 1
    AddPersonListControls i
Next
```

Your form should looks like this (Note: `Form1.ScaleMode` is set to `3-Pixels`):

[image: Dynamically loaded controls]

**Explanation:**

While my answer doesn't directly address your question with the `New` keyword, it shows you the right method how to dynamically add new Controls in the case you don't know how much they should be, thus by avoiding the use of `Named Controls` and by using instead `Array Controls`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but where I should add  AddPersonListControls?

Comment: the answer to this is to broad for a comment, please post a sample of your text file which contain the persons data, and someone will tell you how to read that file.